# “Hearing” the shape of a drum

Tags: real-analysis, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis

It is known that one cannot hear the shape of a drum, i.e. the map from domains in the plane to dirichlet eigenvalues is not one-to-one. But if we allow our differential operator to be any differential operator built up of finitely-many derivatives, can the map from domains in the plane to the eigenvalues of this new operator with dirichlet boundary conditions be one-to-one? If yes, how many dimensions is sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question, and likely one that does not (yet?) have a complete answer.  Indeed, there is a [project on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263791591_Fractals_and_vibrations_Can_you_hear_the_shape_of_a_fractal_drum) which seems to be working along lines relevant to your question.  If you aren't already familiar with this material, [Fractal Zeta Functions](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319447049) offers a somewhat kinder introduction.